# Upgrading from rails 5.2.4 to 6.1 with Delayed Job - Job's not being picked up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Working config

ruby 2.6.2

rails 5.2.4

delayed_job 4.1.8

```rb
#config/environments/development.rb

config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "ukcil_#{Rails.env}"
```

```rb
#config/application.rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

```sh
#Started with

bin/delayed_job -n 1 start
```

```sh
#Environment vairables are

RAILS_ENV=development
QUEUES=*
```

```rb
#config/initializers/delayed_job.rb

Delayed::Worker.queue_attributes = {
  mailers_h: {priority: 0},
  mailers_l: {priority: 10},
  general_h: { priority: 20 },
  general_l: { priority: 30 }
}
```

After upgrading to

Ruby 2.7.2
Rails 6.1.4.1
delayed_job 4.1.9

everything is working except for delayed_job .

Jobs are being queued correctly, appearing delayed_job_web front end view, as before

The delayed_job process is running, as per activity monitor, but the jobs are not being picked up or process.

I just can't see what's changed here. It's not showing any errors.

I thought it would be something esoteric that was causing it. I think it might be, I can find no documentation about a similar problem. Any help with be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was a conflict with another build process which was running.

Comment: Do you recall what the conflict was all about? We have the same issue and seek guidance.